# How to use LSTM as a sequence classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have got the following problem at hand.

I have variable length videos which belong to one of the four classes $A,B,C,D$.

From each frame of a video, I extract a feature vector of length $N$. Hence, for a video of $K$ frames, I've got $K$ such feature vectors.

I'm told that LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) is good for sequence classification. The output of the classifier should be one of $A,B,C,D$. How should I create this model in LSTM?

Input: $K$ vectors of size $N$
Output: $A | B | C | D$

Comment: Welcome to Cross-Validated, Abdul. It's best not to assume that segments of your audience that can help answer your quest has discipline-specific knowledge. To that end, could you edit your question to spell out LSTM before you start using the acronym?

Comment: @Alexis Done. Care to respond to the problem at hand now?

Answer (score 1):

There is some literature to suggest a protocol for this. One paper that is particularly interesting for a first in the analysis of 2-D video images is this one, *Software Analysis of Mining Images for Objects Detection*:

http://actamont.tuke.sk/pdf/2013/n1/8licev.pdf

Here's the abstract:

> The contribution is dealing with the development of the new module of
>   robust FOTOM system for editing images from a video or mining image
>   from measurements for subsequent improvement of detection of required
>   objects in the 2D image. The generated module allows create a final
>   high-quality picture by combination of multiple images with the search
>   objects. We can combine input data according to the parameters or
>   based on reference frames. Correction of detected 2D objects is also
>   part of this module. The solution is implemented into FOTOM system
>   and finished work has been tested in appropriate frames, which were
>   validated core functionality and usability. Tests confirmed the
>   function of each part of the module, its accuracy and implications of
>   integration.

One possible barrier to implementing this approach could be their use of the proprietary FOTOM system.

A more directly relevant approach uses recurrent neural networks, *Action Classification in Soccer Videos with Long Short-Term Memory Recurrent Neural Networks*:

http://liris.cnrs.fr/Documents/Liris-4742.pdf

Here's the abstract to this one:

> In this paper, we propose a novel approach for action classifi- cation
>   in soccer videos using a recurrent neural network scheme. Thereby, we
>   extract from each video action at each timestep a set of features
>   which describe both the visual content (by the mean of a BoW approach)
>   and the dominant motion (with a key point based approach). A Long
>   Short-Term Memory-based Recurrent Neural Network is then trained to
>   classify each video sequence considering the temporal evolution of the
>   features for each timestep. Experimental results on the
>   MICC-Soccer-Actions-4 database show that the proposed approach
>   outperforms classification methods of related works (with a
>   classification rate of 77 %), and that the combination of the two
>   features (BoW and dominant motion) leads to a classification rate of
>   92 %.

Both papers seem to lead to promising results.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the literature. I've upvoted your answer. If I don't get a better answer in a few days, I'll mark this as the answer. :)